# Is there a way to have a block of code repeat while the mouse is held pressed until it is released in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent

I'm making a Conway's Game of Life simulator because I thought that would be a fun project to try out, but I got stuck when trying to implement a function to keep changing cells to alive or dead when I drag my mouse over them.

```
scrollPane.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
    double translation = (SQ_SIZE + SPACING) * SIZE + SPACING;
    double xPosition = e.getX() + scrollPane.hvalueProperty().doubleValue() * (translation - PREF_WIDTH);
    double yPosition = e.getY() + scrollPane.vvalueProperty().doubleValue() * (translation - PREF_HEIGHT);

    // row and column of the click on the grid
    int row = (int) ((yPosition - SPACING * (int) (yPosition / (SQ_SIZE + SPACING))) / SQ_SIZE);
    int col = (int) ((xPosition - SPACING * (int) (xPosition / (SQ_SIZE + SPACING))) / SQ_SIZE);
    
    grid[row][col].setAlive();
});

scrollPane.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
    //??
});
```

This was just to see if I could make the mouse change the cells. I dragged it over to alive and it does not seem to work. It can change the cell where it was initially pressed, but all the other cells do not change.

There is probably a very obvious solution I'm missing, but I'm quite new to JavaFX.

Comment: Look up MouseEvent. There are different types of dragging supported.

Comment: Perhaps you want [drag-and-drop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/drag_drop_feature.htm) (I'm don't understand from your description, exactly what it is that you are trying to do).

Answer (score 2):

Ok so basically you cant use setOnMouseDragged for a scrollpane, so i set it on the gridpane and it worked.